05 Camry 52k miles. Hesitates on starting
05 Camry 52k miles. Hesitates on starting. Alternator or serpentine ? If changing alternator, change belt, water pump, timing belt at same time?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Not sure where you've come to the conclusion this is a charging problem? What exactly do you mean by "hesitates on starting"? Please provide additional information so we can attempt to help you.

Robert, in car talk, we usually use the word "hesitates" to mean that when you're driving and you step on the gas, the car stumbles and fails to respond for a moment, then starts accelerating normally. Is that what you mean? Or is the car simply hard to start? A complete description of what you experience would be helpful. Don't worry, we don't charge by the word. The more info you give, the better.
